# Moq.Setup not returning expected collection?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I have the following code:

```
        var service = new Mock<INavigationService>();

        service.Setup(x => x.GetSchemes(new SchemeFilterEntity())).Returns(new List<SchemeEntity>
            {
                new SchemeEntity
                    {
                        Id = 1,
                        Name = "Test"
                    },
                new SchemeEntity
                    {
                        Id = 2,
                        Name = "Test 2"
                    }
            });

        var sut = service.Object;

        var sut = service.GetSchemes(new SchemeFilterEntity());
```

However when the GetSchemes method is called it returns null?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that should be

> service.Setup(x => x.GetSchemes(It.IsAny< SchemeFilterEntity >())).Returns.....

because otherwise, moq will be looking for that exact instance of the 'new SchemeFilterEntity()' that you passed in in the setup method, which will never match anything else.

Edit: That said, your sut should not be the thing you are mocking, it should be the thing that's using your mocked object.

Comment: yeah - sorry - the last 2 lines are only there to show that trying to call GetSchemes does not return the expected stuff..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are tring to test but if you want "Override" the behavior of `GetSchema`
using a mocked object that method must be `virtual` on the class

If you want to use the mocked object to stub out the INavigationService you have to do the below

```
   .........

    var sut = service.Object;

    SomeThing.UseNavigavtionService(sut); //this is supposed to be the class which you will test.Sut is a mocked INavigationService
```

in your setup you should also use `It.IsAny< SchemeFilterEntity >()` instead of create a concrete object

Comment: I don't want GetSchemes to actually do it's work, I thought the point was to be able to fake the results of the GetSchemes call so that i can use the service in a test? The last 2 lines are only here for illustration.